# Putting password for fabric rsync_project() function

Tags: python, rsync, fabric

I'd like to pass somehow user password for **rsync_project()** function (that is wrapper for regular rsync command) from **Fabric** library.

I've found the option **--password-file=FILE** of rsync command that requires password stored in FILE. This could somehow work but I am looking for better solution as I have (temporarily) passwords stored as plain-text in database.

Please provide me any suggestions how should I work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **rsync** using **ssh** as a remote shell transport is an option and you can setup public key authentication for the users, that would provide you a secure way of doing the rsync without requiring passwords to be entered.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Worked fine for me - no need for passwords any more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using public key authentication as in Pedro's answer is the ideal way to automatically use **rsync**, however in some cases (such as mine) you're stuck using a password as the only means to connect to your target hosts.

YMMV, but my solution was to implement the following function that runs **rsync** via **expect** to type in the password:

```
    def run_rsync(source, target, excludes=[]):
        excludes = "".join(map(lambda e: " --exclude="+e, excludes))
        local("expect -c 'spawn rsync -avz"+excludes+" --force -e \"ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p "+env.port+"\" "+source+" "+target+"; expect password; send \""+env.password+"\\n\"; interact'")
```

Note that this method is insecure since the password will be output to STDOUT when the command is executed, so this should only be used as a last resort and from a trusted environment.